# Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found on npm audit fix

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

While trying to run angular app with 'ng serve' command, first I faced
'**error: digital envelop routines::unsupported**'.

Node.js version 19.8.1

There were suggestion to add flag '`--legacy-peer-deps`' or downgrade node js version.

*It was warned not to use '--legecy-peer-deps' or downgreade node to v17 are hacks that may leave build to security threats.*

The suggestion was to use,

```
npm audit fix --force
```

But after doing audit thought there were some upgrades in some packages in package.json, when I now do 'ng serve' I am getting below error

Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultProject` entry has been [deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11111), just remove it from your `angular.json`.

Comment: Tried it, but after removing 'defautProject' also problem persisted. 
So tried to delete 'node_modules' folder and package-lock.json file, then tried again with 'npm install'.

Now problem in npm install, 'unable to resolve dependency tree' for @angular/compiler and @angular/platform-browser-dynamic.
Tried $npm install --force. Though it solved install issue, but on $ ng serve, now giving exception as 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' not found. The requested module @angular/complier is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.